# Are there any tools for doing a text search within binary data?

Tags: windows, file-search

This question is somewhat related to this so post: [Searching text in binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135643/searching-text-in-binary-data)

I am not looking for a programming solution that involves having to make a program to this.  I was wondering if there were some in OS tools (Windows) or 3rd party programs that would allow me to do the same thing.

Comment: What’s wrong with the `strings (input) | grep (pattern)` answer that was submitted to the other question?  For that matter, have you tried running `grep` directly on the binary data?  (Do `man grep` to check for relevant options.)

Comment: I did see that in the SO, so I revamped the question for Windows which is what I work on more often anyway.  `grep` works on Mac as well, correct?

Comment: Yes grep work on OS X too. By the way, install the GNU version, it's really faster than OS X's default.

Answer (score 3):

[GrepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) and/or [strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) should do.

Comment: And of course Windows has the `find` and `findstr` commands, which are analogous to *nix’s `grep`.  I don’t know how `find` and `findstr` would fare on binary data, but it makes sense to pipe `strings` into one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately using `strings` and piping into `findstr` is rather slow - it took 20 minutes (with an NVMe SSD!) for `strings * | findstr /i foobar` to run, when `grep` (from WSL) ran in under 5 minutes over the same set of files (about 1GB of DLLs/EXEs).